# How to make sure an `useImperativeHandle` ref isn't filled until another ref is filled?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-ref

## tl;dr

I'd like to enforce the following invariant: **when using `useImperativeHandle`, don't fill the ref until some other ref is filled**.

## Long version

### I have weird components

I have a component that uses a custom function for creating a `<canvas>`. This function knows nothing about React and comes from an external library. It returns a methods object that can be used to interact with the canvas.

```js
function createGame(...): GameMethods {...}
```

I also have a component (`NextReactP5Wrapper`) that calls this `createGame` function in a special way and manages the created `<canvas>`

```js
function Game(props) {
  return (
    <NextReactP5Wrapper
      sketch={(p5) => {
        const methods = createGame(props.env, p5)
        return
      }}
    />
  )
}

// Note: React doesn't guarantee that `memo` will not rerender.
// But so far it works, and I haven't found any other way.
const MemoizedGame = React.memo(Game, () => true)
```

### What I want to do

I'd like to make the returned `methods` to be available wherever I'm using `Game`. So I'm using `forwardRef` and `useImperativeHandle`:

```js
const Game = React.forwardRef<GameMethods, { env: GameAttributes }>(
 function Game(props, ref) {
  const methodsRef = React.useRef<GameMethods | null>(null)
  React.useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    // thanks to 'current?' we get a potential null here 
    getFoo: () => methodsRef.current?.getFoo(),
  }))
  return (
    <NextReactP5Wrapper
      sketch={(p5) => {
        const methods = createGame(props.env, p5)
        gameMethods.current = methods
      }}
    />
  )
})

const MemoizedGame = React.memo(Game, () => true)

...elsewhere in my <Page> component
const gameRef = React.useRef<GameMethods>(null)
return <Game ref={gameRef}/>
```

### My problem

Now I have a problem: `gameRef.current` can be null *and* the result of `gameRef.current.getFoo()` can also be null!

### What I want

I'd like to make sure the imperative handle ref isn't filled until the result of `createGame()` is available. Then I can have an easier life, knowing that if `gameRef.current !== null`, I can call of its methods.

Is it possible?

Or should I just write `gameMethods.current!` everywhere I was writing `gameMethods.current?` and hope that everything will be fine?